# List/grid добавление html в Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!
Имею желание сделать разметку страницы на сетку или лист list-view/grid-view. Переключение классов освоил, теперь необходимо изменить последующий код в зависимости от изменения класса.
Как можно добавить классы в зависимости от того выбран list-view или grid-view?
Пример если List:

```
 <div class="list-view">
 <div class="list-item">
 ...
 </div>
 </div>
```

Пример если grid:

```
 <div class="grid-view">
 <div class="grid-item">
 ...
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Предполагая, что какой-то вариант всегда назначен:

```
function ToggleListGrid() {
  $(".list-view, .grid-view").toggleClass("list-view grid-view");
  $(".list-item, .grid-item").toggleClass("list-item grid-item");
}
```